# How do I programmatically change the color behind a pager or repeaters select page number?

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater, paging

I'm a rookie attempting to build an e-commerce site. My pager control that I use to display page numbers uses a repeater, which looks pretty dull. Can anyone show me how to programmatically change the background color of the page number that the user has selected? Or programmatically connect it to a CSS style sheet block of code that does it. Example: change the color behind the number to an orange square with a black border around it. Thanks.

Current code :

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Pager.ascx.cs" Inherits="UserControls_Pager" %> 
<p> Page <asp:Label ID="currentPageLabel" runat="server" /> 
    of <asp:Label ID="howManyPagesLabel" runat="server" /> | 
   <asp:HyperLink ID="previousLink" Runat="server">Previous</asp:HyperLink> 
   <asp:Repeater ID="pagesRepeater" runat="server"> 
      <ItemTemplate> 
         <asp:HyperLink ID="hyperlink" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Page") %>' 
           NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("Url") %>' /> 
      </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:Repeater> 
   <asp:HyperLink ID="nextLink" Runat="server">Next</asp:HyperLink> 
</p>
```

Comment: Can you show your codes ?

Comment: Yes, I add to your question.

Answer (score 1):

UserControl ASPX:

```
 <p> Page <asp:Label ID="currentPageLabel" runat="server" /> of   
 <asp:Label ID="howManyPagesLabel" runat="server" /> | 
 <asp:HyperLink ID="previousLink" Runat="server">Previous</asp:HyperLink> 
 <asp:Repeater ID="pagesRepeater" runat="server" 
        onitemdatabound="pagesRepeater_ItemDataBound"> <ItemTemplate>   
 <asp:HyperLink ID="hyperlink" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Page") %>'   
    NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("Url") %>' /> </ItemTemplate> 
 </asp:Repeater>  
 <asp:HyperLink ID="nextLink" Runat="server">Next</asp:HyperLink> </p>
```

UserControl Code behind:

```
public class p
{
    public string Page { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public p(string url, string page)
    {
        Page = page;
        Url = url;
    }
}
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<p> arr = new List<p>();
    arr.Add(new p("a.aspx", "a"));
    arr.Add(new p("b.aspx", "b"));
    pagesRepeater.DataSource = arr;
    pagesRepeater.DataBind();
}

protected void pagesRepeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    HyperLink lnk = (HyperLink)e.Item.FindControl("hyperlink");
    string[] URL = Request.Url.Segments;
    string currentUrl = URL[URL.Length - 1];
    if (lnk != null)
    {
        string lnkUrl=lnk.NavigateUrl;
        if (lnkUrl == currentUrl)
        {
            lnk.BackColor = Color.Orange;
            lnk.Style.Add("border", "1px solid #000000");
            lnk.Style.Add("background-color", "orange");
            lnk.Style.Add("text-decoration", "none");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was able to do it by adding this CssClass element to my Hyperlink in my XML code. All of the selected pages highlight, except for page #1. Does any one know why the first page will not highlight?:                                                                          CssClass='<%# Eval("Page").ToString() ==
            Request.QueryString["Page"]?
            "RepeaterSelected" : "RepeatedUnselected" %>'

Comment: @user2738382 - for the first page, you probably don't have a `Page` querystring parameter, so the test fails. Maybe use ` Request.QueryString["Page"] ?? "1"` to use a value of "1" when that param is missing.

Comment: @HansKesting - Rookie question. Can you tell me the exact syntax and where I should put it? Would that statment go in the C# side, or the XML side?

Comment: @user2738382 - when you assign that CssClass in your HTML code, use `CssClass='<%# Eval("Page").ToString() == (Request.QueryString["Page"] ?? "1") ? "RepeaterSelected" : "RepeatedUnselected" %>'`

Comment: @HansKesting - Do the double question marks mean "Or"? Does the beginning of that statement mean "if the pages are equal or the page is equal to 1?

Comment: It's the [null coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx). `a ?? b` is `b` if `a` is null, otherwise `a`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that through client side Jquery, for an example if your control that you want to color has an ID "MyControl"

```
                          $("#MyControl").css( "color", "red" ),
```

you don't have to change it from code behind.

Call this code in the document ready of your page as following:

```
                          <script>
                            $(document).ready(function() {
                            $("#MyControl").css( "color", "red" )
                                                          });
                          </script>
```

remember its always better to put your script code at the end of the page as it makes your page run faster.